# Why don't .desktop files on Debian 10 execute?

Tags: debian, gnome, .desktop

I have trouble executing .desktop files in Debian 10.. Do they even run? 
Debian 9 had no issues running the same files I have issues with now.
I have set the files themselves as executable. And in nautilus preferences set "executable text files" to "ask what to do".
Double-click on the software itself (the binary) does execute the software. 
Any help?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=SoftWare
GenericName=SoftWare
Comment=SoftWare
Exec=/home/path/to/softwarebin
Icon=/home/path/to/pixmaps/software.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Encryption;Encryption Tools;Utility;
```

Comment: Debian 10 changed form Xorg to Wayland for Gnome. Any change that might be troubling you here?

Comment: That's probably it.. I just find it strange that they can't build in the same functionality as before.